# How to add array to list view in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

In the below code, why am I not able to load the `features = ["A","B","C"]` to `MyListView`?

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

features = ["A","B","C"]
Builder.load_string("""
<MyListView>:
    ListView:
        item_strings: [str(index) for index in features]
""")

class MyListView(BoxLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MyListView())
```

I am getting following error

```
Message File Name   Line    Position     Traceback              
    <module>    <module5>   21      
    __init__    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py  102     
    __init__    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py 72      
    __init__    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py 320     
    apply   C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py   1970        
    _apply_rule C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py   2130         "BuilderException: Parser: File ""<inline>"", line 4: ...
      2:<MyListView>:
      3:    ListView:
>>    4:        item_strings: [str(index) for index in features] ... BuilderException: Parser: File ""<inline>"", line 4: ...
      2:<MyListView>:
      3:    ListView:
>>    4:        item_strings: [str(index) for index in features] ... NameError: name 'features' is not defined   File ""C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py"", line 1742, in create_handler
    return eval(value, idmap), bound_list   File ""<string>"", line 4, in <module>

  File ""C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py"", line 2115, in _apply_rule
    rctx['ids'])   File ""C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py"", line 1747, in create_handler
    cause=tb) "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp


Builder.load_string("""
<MyListView>:
    ListView:
        item_strings: [str(index) for index in root.features]
""")


class MyListView(BoxLayout):
    features = ["A", "B", "C"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(MyListView())
```

I suggest you read [this](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) if you haven't before.